# A big block or multiple small blocks of BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT TRAN

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, transactions

I have a stored procedure which does hundreds of different transaction tasks (DELETE/INSERT/UPDATE). Surprisingly, they are grouped in a big BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT TRAN block.It used to work well but recently the stored procedure runs too long as the data accumulating.

My question is: Is there any performance gain if I separate them into multiple 
smaller BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT TRAN blocks. If not, what would be the solution? Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2012

Comment: I have done a simple test by splitting the big block into four blocks. The execution time was reduced from 110 to 80 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off course there will be a performance gain when you will break a single transaction into multiple pieces. Because after completion of small transaction statements data will be committed. It will consume less disk space as it has to maintain less transaction logs. If the tables are unrelated then feel free to define multiple transaction. Statements getting executed under one transaction should be logically complete on itself.